# Pace-js not working with Axios inside Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios, pace

I have the following axios call:

```js
//Pace.restart();
Pace.start();
axios.post(`${this.url_base}/${this.system}`, consulta)
.then((response) => {
    console.log(response);
})
.catch((error) => {
    console.log(error.response.data);
})
.then(() => {
    Pace.stop();
});
```

However Pace.start() simply won't fire and Pace.restart() will flash briefly instead of waiting for the stop signal from axios. What am I doing wrong?